# how to create a view with multiple models mvc 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

so i works in asp.net mvc 4 project and i have a problem in my view, what i want is create a view with 2 differnt type of model,first view (Index) take IEnumerable (Models.myModel) the second (subscriber Details) take Models.myModel, **this is my Model code :**

```
public class SubscribersModel
{

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [StringLength(maximumLength: 10, MinimumLength = 7)]
    public string cin { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime birthday { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string birthplace { get; set; }
  }
```

**My controller code :**

```
 public class SubscribersController : Controller
{
    private AgencyDbEntities dbcontext = new AgencyDbEntities();
    private Subscribe sb = new Subscribe();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var subscribers = from sb in dbcontext.Subscribes select new SubscribersModel {      cin = sb.cin, name = sb.name, birthday = (DateTime)sb.birthDay, birthplace = sb.birthPlace   };

        return View(subscribers);
    }

    public ActionResult Details(string id,string cin,string name)
    {
        var subscriber = new SubscribersModel();
        IEnumerable<Subscribe> list = from s in dbcontext.Subscribes select s;
        foreach (var sb in list)
        {
            if (sb.cin == id)
            {
                subscriber.cin = sb.cin;
                subscriber.name = sb.name;
                subscriber.birthday = (DateTime)sb.birthDay;
                subscriber.birthplace = sb.birthPlace;
            }
        }
        return View(subscriber);
    }
 }
```

**My index view :**

```
  @model IEnumerable<_3SDWebProject.Models.SubscribersModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Subscribers";
}
    <div class="sidebar">
      //here i want to show my details view
     </div>
 <div class="content" style="width: 700px; margin-left: 250px; height: 545px;margin-  top: -30px;">
  <h2>Subscribers</h2>
<p>
     @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

 @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Table.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <table class="altrowstable" id="alternatecolor">
 <tr>
    <th>
        CIN
    </th>
    <th>
        Name
    </th>
    <th>
        birthday
    </th>
    <th>
        birthplace
    </th>
     <th class="operations">
        Operations
    </th>
</tr>

 @foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.cin)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.birthday)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.birthplace)
    </td>
    <td>
      @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.cin }, new { @class = "details-logo"})
     </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
</div>
```

**my Details view :**

```
@model _3SDWebProject.Models.SubscribersModel

<fieldset>
<legend>SubscribersModel</legend>

<div class="display-label">
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.name)
</div>
<div class="display-label">
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.birthday)
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.birthday)
</div>

<div class="display-label">
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.birthplace)
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.birthplace)
</div>
</fieldset>
```

so please if someone have any idea or solution i will be very appreciate:
NB:this a picture describe what i want
[image]

Comment: A View should be related to one model only. You can combine both models into one and use that combined model in the view.

Comment: I would disagree with this. A view can very well , and sometimes must, be related to as many models as needed. This is why I use something I call a 'View Model' (even if it's not absolutly correct), a class in between the models and the view, to build the proper in memory structure, that will be passed to the view. But in no way this can be named a "model". Remember that, if you are using EF Code First, creating a new model "combined" will in fact result in a new table in your database. I doubt that's the goal....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a new, compound view model that includes both of these view models.

```
public class CompoundViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SubscribersModel> AllSubscribers {get; set;} 
    public SubscribersModel SelectedSubscriber {get; set;}
}
```

Ideally also split your view into partial views and render these two part of your compound model into them using `DisplayFor<>` or `EditorFor<>`.  That way you can reuse the view for a 'SubscriberModel' elsewhere in the application if you need it.

Your controller code could also be improved by using a dependency injection framework (e.g. Autofac) to inject those dependencies that you are currently newing up.

Another alternative, given that you are using the same model for the list and the details view, would be to handle this client-side using Javascript, either manually using jQuery or with one of the newer frameworks that allows client-side model binding like Knockout.js or Angular.js.

Comment: Thanks @lan it works perfectly, i create a class that contains the two model.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a second view called `Details` which is strongly typed with `SubscribersModel`

```
@model _3SDWebProject.Models.SubscribersModel
```

Right-click anywhere in the code for your `Details()` action
Select Add View...
Leave "Details" for View name
Check "Create a strongly-typed view"
Select your `SubscribersModel` from the Model class dropdown
Scaffold template: Details
Click "Add"

Comment: i already do it the problem is i can't works with two different models type in the same view

Comment: Whoops, I see the left side of your SS.