# How to reference multiple models in same MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller, razor

I've been trying to dissect an automated MVC view & controller, and modify it so that i can insert information from a form in the view, on to two separate database tables (Entity framework database first).

here's what i have so far. it works if i reference either of the namespaces at the top on their own, but not together?

```
@model manage.mysite.DataModels.Property_Type
@model manage.mysite.DataModels.Room_Type

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Property_Type</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PropertyType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PropertyType, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PropertyType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoomType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RoomType, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoomType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to reference several models in a View.

However, you can create composite model, which has the two other models as properties.

As such:

```
using manage.mysite.DataModels;

namespace manage.mysite.ViewModels
{ 
    public class FooViewModel
    {
        public Property_Type PropertyType { get; set; }
        public Room_Type RoomType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And then serve this model instead.

```
@model manage.mysite.ViewModels.FooViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Property_Type</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PropertyType.PropertyType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PropertyType.PropertyType, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PropertyType.PropertyType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoomType.RoomType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RoomType.RoomType, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoomType.RoomType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

See also:

[MVC Multiple Models in One View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30925122/mvc-multiple-models-in-one-view?rq=1)

[how to create a view with multiple models mvc 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16219103/how-to-create-a-view-with-multiple-models-mvc-4?rq=1)

[Which is the best way to use multiple models with sames properties and using a unique view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839623/which-is-the-best-way-to-use-multiple-models-with-sames-properties-and-using-a-u?rq=1)